# sony spresense で利用可能なカメラモジュールとサンプルコード

Tags: 画像, camera, spresense

sony spresense で利用可能なカメラモジュールとサンプルコードはあるのでしょうか？
2018/8/20現在，Spresenseのサイトにはカメラの情報はほとんど見つかりませんし，FAQにも[関連する見出し](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/support/spresense-faq/#_can_i_connect_a_camera_to_spresense)はあるものの，内容が何も記載されていないようです．
[仕様のページ](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/specifications)には"Dedicated parallel interface"とあるだけですが，これは専用品（これから発売される？）でないと動作しないということでしょうか．
[Schema](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-hw-design-files/blob/master/CXD5602PWBMAIN1/schematics/en_schematics.pdf)には20pinとあるので，15pinのラズパイ用カメラは（少なくとも直接は）使えなさそうなことはわかります．
情報があればいただけると助かります．

Answer (score 2):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
お問い合わせの件について、回答いたします。

SPRESENSEで利用可能なカメラボードは、2018年の秋に発売予定のSPRESENSEカメラボードのみとなります。

技術ドキュメントならびにサンプルプログラムも、発売と同じ時期に公開する予定です。

恐れ入りますが、今しばらくお待ちください。
どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

**■ 2018年11月29日追記**

大変ながらくお待たせいたしました。SPRESENSEカメラの出荷を開始いたしました。
また、サンプルプログラムにつきましてもバージョン 1.1.0 以降で追加されています。

ご検討の一助となれば、幸いです。

Comment: 回答を更新いたしました。ご覧ください。

Comment: 回答・更新，ありがとうございます．